# Including native DLLs in C# exe

Tags: c#, .net

My project uses several dependencies that contain native libraries. These are OpenTK (`glfw3.dll`), ImGui.NET (`cimgui.dll`) and AssimpNet (`assimp.dll`). These native libraries are, of course, different for each architecture, but I'd like to know if there's a way to include these DLLs in the EXE files for each architecture.
It should also be noted that I use Rider.

The project is configured to publish a single file. The built exe contains all dependencies, as expected, but not the native DLLs. The properties of the project are as follows:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I build the project using the following command: `dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64`

Comment: Only managed libraries can be part of a c# exe file.  The c++ dll can automatically be installed in the setup.exe file created by publishing  VS you can add existing item and then browse to the dll file.  Then in solution explorer right click on the dll and under properties set the copy option.   When the c# gets built the c++ dll get copied to the bin folder.  You can then use DllImport and Marshal methods to access the c++.

Comment: It's possible (but a real pain) to link together .NET code (which may be C#) with native object files (which may be bundled in .lib static library archives) into a single resulting  "mixed-mode assembly" EXE or DLL.  `link.exe` has this functionality to support the C++/CLI compiler.  The key to making it happen is to tell the various .NET compilers to generate `.netmodule` files which `link.exe` accepts as input.  Once any of the code, native or managed, is already linked into a DLL (or EXE), it's too late.